# Radio button to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I current have a form using radio buttons to choose an item. what I want to do is based on which radio button that is selected add a certain number of days to today's current date. I am unsure of a way to do this but my current idea was to use a IF statement to compare which button is selected and if it is than add a number to the getDate() value. I am currently working on line 42/43. This is my code so far:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Digital Photos</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="../../index.htm" title="Index">Web Program Homepage</a><br>
<a href="../home.htm" title="Index">ITWP Course Homepage</a>
<p>
<form>
Select the type of item you want to order:
<br>
<input type="radio" name="order" onclick="check(this.value)" value="Hard-Copy Print">Hard-Copy Print<br>
<input type="radio" name="order" onclick="check(this.value)" value="Poster">Poster<br>
<input type="radio" name="order" onclick="check(this.value)" value="Coffee Mug">Coffee Mug<br>
<input type="radio" name="order" onclick="check(this.value)" value="T-Shirt">T-Shirt<br>
<br>
You are ordering a: <input type="text" id="answer" size="20">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
function check(order){
  document.getElementById("answer").value=order;
}
var today = new Date();
var dd = today.getDate();
var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

if(dd<10) {
    dd='0'+dd
} 

if(mm<10) {
    mm='0'+mm
} 

today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
document.write("Todays date is " + today);
if
document.write(". Your order will be ready on " + today);
/* ]]> */
</script>
<p></p>
<a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer" title="HTML5 Validation">HTML5 Validation</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, this is clearly a homework assignment, and I, at least, will not write code for you.  I'll be glad to help with problems once you've written some code, and not just an "idea."  In the meantime, be sure you're using the "console" tab in Chrome's developer tools or Firefox's Firebug.

Comment: @Zack, if you want people helping you, you should go back to the previous questions you have submitted on StackOverflow and select/approve the answers that have helped you. Be a good SO citizen!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I can see that this is perhaps an assignment - but I for one learn best by example. That said, you need to look over the code and understand it (or else you will never really get good at programming).

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Digital Photos</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="../../index.htm" title="Index">Web Program Homepage</a><br>
    <a href="../home.htm" title="Index">ITWP Course Homepage</a>

    <form>
        Select the type of item you want to order:
        <br>
        <div onchange="check()">
            <input type="radio" name="order" value="Hard-Copy Print">Hard-Copy Print<br>
            <input type="radio" name="order" value="Poster">Poster<br>
            <input type="radio" name="order" value="Coffee Mug">Coffee Mug<br>
            <input type="radio" name="order" value="T-Shirt">T-Shirt<br>
            <br>
        </div>
    </form>

    <div id="orderDetails"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    /* <![CDATA[ */
    function check() {

        var nodeList = document.getElementsByName("order");
        var value;

        for (var i = 0; i < nodeList.length; i++)
        {
            if(nodeList[i].checked)
            {
                value = nodeList[i].value;
                break;
            }
        }

        var today = new Date();
        var arrival = new Date();

        if (value == "Hard-Copy Print")
        {
            //If this one is selected, shipment arrive at current time + 1 day
            arrival.setDate(today.getDate() + 1)
        }
        else if (value == "Poster")
        {
            //If this one is selected, shipment arrive at current time + 2 days
            arrival.setDate(today.getDate() + 2)
        }
        else if (value == "Coffee Mug")
        {
            //If this one is selected, shipment arrive at current time + 3 days
            arrival.setDate(today.getDate() + 3)
        }
        else if (value == "T-Shirt")
        {
            //If this one is selected, shipment arrive at current time + 4 days
            arrival.setDate(today.getDate() + 4)
        }
        else
        {
            alert("Something went really really reeeeeeeeealy wrong :)");
        }


        var dd = today.getDate();
        var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
        var yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        if(dd<10) {
            dd='0'+dd
        } 

        if(mm<10) {
            mm='0'+mm
        }

        var dd2 = arrival.getDate();
        var mm2 = arrival.getMonth() + 1; //January is 0!
        var yyyy2 = arrival.getFullYear();

        if (dd2 < 10) {
            dd2 = '0' + dd2
        }

        if (mm2 < 10) {
            mm2 = '0' + mm2
        }

        today = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;
        arrival = mm2 + '/' + dd2 + '/' + yyyy2;

        var details = "You are ordering: " + value + "<br/><br/> Todays date is " + today + "<br/><br/>" + "Your order will be ready on " + arrival;

        document.getElementById("orderDetails").innerHTML = details;
    }

</script>
<p></p>
<a href="http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer" title="HTML5 Validation">HTML5 Validation</a>
```

Comment: I am curious is there a way to make the output not load on a new page but in a text box that's on the same page, dynamically updating depending on which button is chosen?

Comment: Yes...get rid of the document.write, create a div somewhere on the page, and use that div-id to set an innerHTML...I edited my answer which illustrates this.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to have the radio values as strings that could be used as keys in an array:

```
<input type="radio" name="order" onclick="check(this.value)" value="hard_copy_print">Hard-Copy Print<br>
<input type="radio" name="order" onclick="check(this.value)" value="poster">Poster<br>
<input type="radio" name="order" onclick="check(this.value)" value="coffee_mug">Coffee Mug<br>
<input type="radio" name="order" onclick="check(this.value)" value="t_shirt">T-Shirt<br>
```

Then have a keyed array storing the order times for each item:

```
var orderTimes = array('hard_copy_print' => 4, 'poster' => 2, 'coffee_mug' => 6, 't_shirt' => 8);
```

Then use the value of the radio item to get the order time.